# Different form opens when you login as admin c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

So i've made a login form in c# working with MySql and i want to make it so when administrator login a different form pops up i've made on the mysql in the users database a column named permissions so if a user will have permission Admin i want a different form to open for him and not the same as for normal users but i don't really know how to do that

the code:

```
private void btn_Prijava_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * from login.users where upIme='" + this.tB_upIme.Text + "' AND geslo='" + this.tB_geslo.Text + "' ;", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Uspešno ste se prijavili!");
                this.Hide();
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.ShowDialog();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dvojno uporabniško ime in geslo!");
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Uporabniško ime ali geslo ni pravilno!");
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**!

Comment: ill change that later on but whats important now is i just need to open a diferent form if admin logins..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have `permissions` column and have value `Admin` for admin users you can try thebelow code.

```
       bool IsAdminUser=false; 
       while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
            IsAdminUser = myReader["permissions"].ToString().Equals("Admin");
        }
        if (count == 1 && IsAdminUser==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User is Admin!");
            this.Hide();
            AdminForm adminForm = new AdminForm ();
            adminForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uspešno ste se prijavili!");
            this.Hide();
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dvojno uporabniško ime in geslo!");
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: There is never any reason to write `? true : false`

Comment: @SLaks: sorry dear i didn't get your point , could you please explain if there is anything wrong?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: Do you understand what `x ? true : false` means? Why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: @SLaks: i realized it,yes `?:` is not necessary :) Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

private void cmdEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234";
                    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

```
                MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * from boardinghousedb.employee_table where username='" + this.txtUsername.Text + "' AND password='" + this.txtPassword.Text + "' ;", myConn);

                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                myConn.Open();
                myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;

                bool IsAdminUser = false;
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    IsAdminUser = myReader["username"].ToString().Equals("admin");
                }
                if (count == 1 && IsAdminUser == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("User is Admin!");
                    this.Hide();
                    AdminForm adminForm = new AdminForm();
                    adminForm.ShowDialog();
                }
                else if (count == 1)
                {

                    this.Hide();
                    Menu f3 = new Menu();
                    f3.ShowDialog();
                }

                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and Password . . . Access Denied", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is Not Correct . . . Please try again", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    myConn.Close();
                }

                myConn.Close();
             }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }     
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.